# want to change the color of text in multiple choice listview

Tags: android, listview

I have the multiple choice list as shown in fig

[image]

I have 2 problems

1. But in my all application screens have background white.. here is the same case if i made my screen white, all the text "BlackBerry", "Nokia" etc disappeared because by default the text color is white.. so please tell me how to change the text color to **black**? I tried style but it wont work.
2. There is some problem with checked positions i get.. e.g. if check one of the item and later if i unchecked, still it show the item is selected even if it is unchecked..

Here is my code for checked items selection

```
private void doDownloading() {
        SparseBooleanArray sp = listTrackView.getCheckedItemPositions();

        for (int i = 0; i < sp.size(); i++) {
            selectedConferenceList.add(conferenceList.get(sp.keyAt(i))
                    .getConferenceName());
        }
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At last I got to know there is no way that you can change the text color of multiple choice listview with standard `ArrayAdapter<String>`. So I go for custom adapter implementation.
[This](http://appfulcrum.com/2010/09/18/listview-example-4-custom-layout-checkbox-imagebutton-textview/) link is helpful for me in developing the custom adapter with multi-choice implementation.

Answer (score 0):

This is an example code, you can change as your's

**AndroidMultiChoiceListActivity .java**

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class AndroidMultiChoiceListActivity extends Activity {

 ListView choiceList;
 String[] choice = { "Choice A", 
   "Choice B", "Choice C", "Choice D", "Choice E"};

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        choiceList = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);

        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter
        = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, 
          android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice, 
          choice);
        choiceList.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);
        choiceList.setAdapter(adapter);

    }
}
```

**main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >
<TextView  
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:text="@string/hello"
    android:textColor="#334422"
    />
<ListView 
    android:id="@+id/list"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    />
</LinearLayout>
```

In your Textview use `android:textColor="#334422"` to change the color of text.

Comment: Change the color as your wish

Comment: I have already implemented it.. But i need customization over it.. Read the question carefully

Comment: in where you change text color, in xml either activity?

Comment: in the list where i mentioned "Blackberry","Nokia" etc.. The point is i haven't implemented custom adapter instead i have ArrayAdadpter<String>..

Comment: I hope in your custom adapter you definitely use a textview, am i right?